# how can i add button Google+ Sign-In?

Tags: java, android, google-plus, google-plus-signin

I installed the Google Play Services in the SDK, and then added to its 'Layout' button code Google

```
    <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

there is a bug:

```
Rendering Problems The following classes could not be found:
- com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton (Fix Build Path, Create Class)
 Tip: Try to build the project.
```

i add a line at my build file:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])


--> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0'


testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile files('libs/bolts-android-1.2.1.jar')
compile files('libs/Parse-1.10.3.jar')
}
```

but it still doesn't work. How can i make button appearence?

Comment: I think you added the incorrect plugin. Refer here. https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating#add_the_google_services_plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You added wrong dependency. You should add this for sign-in button.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

dependency you added is only for ads

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0'
```

Should be

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
```